# How to disable the "sign in to wifi network" page?

Tags: wi-fi

How can I disable the page "sign in to wifi network" that appears when connected to a wifi network that requires login?

I dont want to disable wifi. I just dont want this page to appear. Is it possible?

Comment: Extra question: does the WiFi actually have a captive portal (i.e. a page for you to login)? If it does, it's best you don't touch this feature for your own convenience.

Comment: This page appears while I'm driving and it hides the GPS app for minutes until it disappears. I don't want to disable wifi because getting internet at a red light is useful for updating traffic information.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, no

basically, some WiFi providers will put a sign in page after you connect, so that you sign into your account which you paid for, or to be able to limit your time on the web unless you pay, or they'll give you free WiFi only if you subscribe to something etc.

So, what you're trying to do, in short, is get free WiFi in a place where they want you to pay.

There are a few tricks to try but chances are, that it's not going to work.

1. If the sign in page lets you download their app without signing in first, then what you can do is, press on the download option, it will open the play store, and while play store is open, you can go anywhere on the web,
2. Or you can use a VPN that blocks your activity from the WiFi provider and will let you bypass the sign in page and in turn you'll have free WiFi. Though it's hard to find one that will actually work.

Comment: Good explanation on what captive portals are used to. But "most cases no" seems not to be correct, see the linked dupe: `adb shell "settings put global captive_portal_detection_enabled 0"` should do the trick.

Comment: No I am not trying to get free wifi. I just dont want this page to appear because when I'm driving it hides the GPS app.

Comment: @John that's what the answer in the linked post (see the text box in your question) says :) Glad to read it works for you as well!

Comment: @Izzy Yes but I wanted to let you know.